# Exponentially small effects in black hole physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, black-holes, spacetime, quantum-information

On [page 60 of the following paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.04891)<sup>1</sup>, it is written:

> But in gravity, due to exponentially small effects of $O(\exp(−Area/G_N ))$, associated with black-hole physics, even these dressed versions of local operators don’t make precise sense. This is a concrete sense in which any notion of spacetime becomes ambiguous in quantum gravity, highlighting that e.g. the breakdown of locality in the context of the black-hole information paradox is an effect of $O(\exp(−S_{BH}))$, and is otherwise invisible to every order in $G_N$.

I've never encountered this term before. Namely, from where do these effects of $O(\exp(−Area/G_N)$ arise in black hole physics? Any insights or further references explaining their origin would be greatly appreciated.

---

<sup>1</sup> N. Arkani-Hamed, T.-C. Huang, Y.-t. Huang, "Scattering Amplitudes For All Masses and Spins", arXiv:1709.04891.

Comment: I think this term ($exp(-Area/G_N)$) comes from the entropy-area law initially proposed by Bekenstein. ($Entropy \to -\rho\ln \rho => \rho \alpha exp(-Entropy)$ and $Entropy \to Area/l_p^2$ with $l_p$ the Planck length, the square of which is proportional to Newton's gravitational constant.)